# Difference between a submodular function and a linear function is submodular

Tags: functions

My lecture notes for submodularity states:

> If f is submodular and g is a linear function then so is −g and thus f − g is submodular

I'm not entirely sure what this means. How would one define a linear function with respect to a set function?

Comment: In this context, a "linear" function on a finite set $\mathscr S$ is a function  $F$ obtained by assigning a weight (some real number) $w_i$ to each element $i\in \Omega$ and then letting $F(S)=\sum_{i\in S} w_i$  for $S\in 2^{\mathscr S}$.  Such a function is clearly submodular, and the sum of submodular functions is itself submodular.  See, e.g., [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Submodular_set_function)